# Can anyone tell me where i am wrong in this condition?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to restrict that if the program name already exists and the concatenated value does not exist then push the concatenated value otherwise do nothing but still, my concatenated value is getting pushed into the database.

Here is the code:

```
public void addProgramAndDepartmentName(String programName, String departmentName) {    
    final DatabaseReference rootRef;
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    String programAndDepartmentName = programName + departmentName;

    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if ( !(snapshot.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).exists()) ) {    
                rootRef.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).push().child("Program Name").setValue(programAndDepartmentName).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        /*AddCourses addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse = new AddCourses();
                        addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.getDataIntoSpinnerFromFirebase();
                        addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {    
                            Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department is not Added into Database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }    
                        else {    
                            Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department name is added into Database if.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();    
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if( (snapshot.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).exists() ) &&
                    ( !( snapshot.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).child("Program Name").child(programAndDepartmentName).exists() ) ) ) {
                rootRef.child("Program & Departments").child(programName).push().child("Program Name").setValue(programAndDepartmentName).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)  {    
                        /*AddCourses addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse = new AddCourses();
                        addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.getDataIntoSpinnerFromFirebase();
                        addProgramNameToSpinnerInAddCourse.spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department is not Added into Database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }    
                        else {    
                            Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "Program and Department name is added into Database else if.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();    
                        }
                    }
                });
            }    
            else {    
                Toast.makeText(AddPrograms.this, "This " + programName + " already Exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();    
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {    
        }
    });    
}
```

but the only condition that is working correctly is is first one the condition after And is not working

And here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "Program & Departments" : {
    "Bs" : {
      "-MV4Heye6EkKPMFlL9IX" : {
        "Program Name" : "Bscs"
      },
      "-MV4Hfy_MHv0CVCnlsRZ" : {
        "Program Name" : "Bscs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

please guide me where I am wrong?

Comment: There is not enough information here. Please show how `snapshot` is initialized, and the JSON for `snapshot` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: i have added complete code and jason file too

Comment: Thanks for that. What isn't working about the code you shared? It might be useful to also tell us what, given specific values for `programName` and `departmentName`, you want the JSON to become.

Comment: The programName is "Bs" and the departmentName is "cs" and i have made this code to take program name and department name in 2 separate fields and then concatenate them and after that, I am using if-else statement to check whether the program name exists or not if not exist then make a node with the name of the program name and then add the concatenated value beneath.

Comment: it and else-if the statement is used to check if program name already exists or not and if it exists then check if the concatenated value already exists beneath it or not and if a concatenated value already existed than do nothing and if concatenated value not exist than put the concatenated value beneath the already existed node named with program name. And the part which is not working in it is else-if statement which is adding the concatenated value even if it is already present in the db.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Thank you Frank van Puffelen I read your answer but I didn't get it. I tried my own way and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single node with a specific value to exist, make that value the key of that node:

```
{
  "Program & Departments" : {
    "Bs" : {
      "Bscs": true
    }
  }
}
```

With this structure, the path `/Program & Departments/Bs/Bscs` is guaranteed to exist only once, since the JSON can only contain that path only once.

You can then check if the path exists, and create it if not, with a single transaction:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child(programName).child(programAndDepartmentName);
ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        if (!mutableData.exists())
            mutableData.setValue(true);
        }
        return Transaction.success(mutableData)
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        Log.d(TAG, "runTransaction:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```